# How to plot layered graphs?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

Given a [directed acyclic graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-to-generate-random-directed-acyclic-graphs), there is always a possibility to plot the graph as layers, where nodes always send edges into one direction (usually down), to successive layers, and never backwards. The `"LayeredDrawing"` option value for `GraphLayout` fails miserably. There is the built-in (but somewhat obsolete) `LayeredGraphPlot`, which can do this, but it is obviously not part of the new `Graph`-paradigm. What would be an efficient and elegant algorithm to lay such a graph in 2D?

```
Row@{
  Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 5}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, VertexLabels -> (# -> # & /@ Range@5), 
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", ImagePadding -> 10],

  LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 5}, 
   VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> 200]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that while `TopologicalSort` gives a top-down sorting of vertices, usually there are multiple solutions for topological sorting, thus multiple ways to layer the same graph. Also, the algorithm must take into account that not all children of a parent should end up on the same layer (see e.g. vertex `1` in the right plot). A nice algorithm for laying out arrows is welcome as well.

Comment: I use `LayeredGraphPlot`.  It helps to compute the transitive reduction of your graph first (if you want to draw all the edges, pick off the vertex coordinates from the layered plot of the transitive reduction and then plot the full graph). Transitive reduction was implemented in Combinatorica, but it's not included for Mathematica 8 Graph objects.  Fortunately, they give you `TopologicalSort`, so it's fairly easy to implement.

Comment: I should add that `LayeredGraphPlot` does, in fact, work with Mathematica 8 native `Graph` objects.

Comment: `GraphPlot` and related functions are far from obsolete in v8.  `Graph` can't do everything they can (e.g. multigraphs).  Graph drawing is complex enough to be a research field on its own so I am not sure if it's worthwhile trying to implement your own algorithm for this.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245946/vertexcoordinate-rules-and-vertexlist-from-graphplot-graphic/4250069#4250069. It converts the layout of the old graph towards the new graph?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was about to give this a second go and implement a layout algorithm manually based on [Szabolcs's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1856/89), when I realized that since v9, we have built-in options to lay out trees and directed acyclic graphs in the above specified layered way:

```
SetOptions[Graph, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 9};
Prepend[
  Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> #, PlotLabel -> If[ListQ@#, Column@#, #]] & /@ {
  "LayeredEmbedding", {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1}, 
  "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left},
  {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Tolerance" -> .5}},
 LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Top, VertexLabeling -> True, PlotLabel -> "LayeredGraphPlot"]]
```

[image]

Note that simple `"LayeredEmbedding"` still produces the wrong layout (`1` is below `2`), but now a `"RootVertex"` option can specify the root node. I've included `LayeredGraphPlot` for comparison. `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` was specifically added in v9 for directed acyclic graphs. Its submethod options can be used to tweak the position of the root, orientation and the tolerance used in terminating the energy minimization process.

One could get the vertex coordinates as follows:

```
coord = {};
Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (Disk[AppendTo[coord, #2 -> #1]; #1, .1] &)]
coord
```

> ```
> {1 -> {0., 4.}, 2 -> {1., 3.}, 3 -> {-2., 3.}, 5 -> {-1., 3.}, 8 -> {0., 3.},
>  4 -> {1., 2.}, 6 -> {0., 1.}, 7 -> {1., 1.}, 10 -> {-1., 2.}, 9 -> {0., 0.}}
> ```

Check out the [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html) option because it contains some more layout methods in v9!

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** I am assuming that you are interested in coming up with a layout algorithm, and not just getting a pretty plot with whatever Mathematica has built in.

---

I will admit right now that I do not know how this is usually done, but here's a naive idea for a starting point:

Let's put vertex $v$ on layer number $n$ if $n$ is the maximal distance of $v$ from any other vertex.  This will not give the same thing as `LayeredGraphPlot`, but it's a good approximation.  Here's an implementation:

```
amat   = AdjacencyMatrix[graph];
paths  = NestWhileList[amat.# &, amat, Total[#, 2] > 0 &];
layers = Max /@ Transpose@Total@Clip@Accumulate@Reverse[paths];

SortBy[Thread[VertexList[graph] -> layers], Last]
```

It will return a list of the form `vertex -> layerNumber`.

It is based on the observation that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then $(A^k)_{ij}$ will give the number of paths of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

Answer (score 4):

Use [this answer by Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250069/695132).

```
test = LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4,
2 -> 4, 1 -> 5}, VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> 200]
getLabelCoordinateMap[gp1_] := 
Module[{points, labels, actualLabels, coordAliases, actualCoords}, 
points = 
Cases[gp1, GraphicsComplex[points_, __] :> points, Infinity] // 
 First;
 labels = Cases[gp1, Text[___], Infinity];
actualLabels = labels[[All, 1, 1]];
coordAliases = labels[[All, 2]];
actualCoords = points[[coordAliases]];
Thread[actualLabels -> actualCoords]];

coord = getLabelCoordinateMap[test]
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 5}, 
ImageSize -> 200, VertexLabels -> (# -> # & /@ Range@5), 
VertexCoordinates -> coord, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

It gives the following:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The problem with this method is twofold: first, I have to run `LayeredGraphPlot`, which involves a lot of unnecessary computation (I assume), and second, I still don't have a layering algorithm.