# Transform an expression into a graph that can be plotted with TreeGraph (not TreeForm)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement, expression-manipulation, trees

I would like to plot an expression (like `TreeForm` does), but using the new `TreeGraph` functionality.

`TreeGraph` takes as input a set of edges (of the form `a -> b`), so it seems that to solve the problem it is necessary to turn an expression into a set of edges. For example `Sin[Plus[a, b]]` would need to be transformed into: `{Sin -> Plus, Plus -> a, Plus -> b}`.

How can this transformation be done for any *Mathematica* expression?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, scaramouche! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to [do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, do the fandango...). I also formatted your code for you. Here's a [guide to show you how for next time](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: +Very good challenge!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Any advantage in using TreeGraph instead of TreeForm?

Comment: @Jepessen Output of `TreeForm` produces just graphics. Output of `TreeGraph` gives a `Graph` object which carries complete information about graph and can be computed with.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649473/353410?

Answer (score 8):

Method starts off by replacing all heads in the expression with the appropriate node index, then deduces the edge list by parsing the substituted node-index-expression. Note that input expression must be wrapped in `Hold` (or `HoldComplete`) to prevent evaluation of e.g. `Plus[1, 2]` into `3`.

```
(* sow node -> label replacements *)
sowLabel[x_?AtomQ] := (Sow[# -> x]; #) &[c++];
sowLabel[x_] := x;

(* sow parent -> child replacements *)
sowEdge[head_[arg__]] := (Sow[head -> #] & /@ {arg}; head);
sowEdge[x_?AtomQ] := x;

(* the expression to be parsed into a tree *)
expr = Hold[Log[Sin[1 + 2], ToExpression["1" <> "0"]]];
FullForm@expr
```

> ```
> Hold[Log[Sin[Plus[1, 2]], ToExpression[StringJoin["1", "0"]]]]
> ```

```
(* replace heads with node index & collect index -> label list *)
c = 1;
{new, labels} = Reap@ReleaseHold@Map[sowLabel, expr, {2, \[Infinity]}, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {
>   1[2[3[4, 5]], 6[7[8, 9]]],
>   {{1 -> Log, 2 -> Sin, 3 -> Plus, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 6 -> ToExpression, 7 -> StringJoin, 8 -> "1", 9 -> "0"}}
> }
> ```

```
(* create graph edges from substituted expression *)
edges = Sort@Most@First@Last@Reap@Map[sowEdge, {new}, {0, \[Infinity]}]
```

> ```
> {1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9}
> ```

```
(* plot results *)
{
 TreeGraph[edges,
  VertexLabels -> First@labels, ImagePadding -> {{1, 35}, {0, 10}}
  ],
 LayeredGraphPlot[edges,
  VertexLabeling -> True,
  VertexRenderingFunction :> (Inset[
      Framed[InputForm[#2 /. First@labels], Background -> Hue[.15, .3, 1]], #1] &)
  ],
 TreeForm[expr, ImageSize -> 230]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Hold[Log[Sin[Plus[1, 2]], ToExpression[StringJoin["1", "0"]]]]
```

Note, that `TreeForm` keeps the `Hold` wrapper.

Comment: Many thanks István.  You solution using TreeGraph is almost what I need.  But it has a problem: TreeGraph chooses by itself which node should be the root.  So, for example, if you try the expression Sin[Plus[a,b]], it will place Plus at the top (when it should be Sin).  Is there a way to fix the root of the tree?

Comment: @scaramouche: Yes, I am aware of it, that's why I suggested using `LayeredGraphPlot` instead. If you insist on `TreeGraph`, you can extract `VertexCoordinates` from the `LayeredGraphPlot` and lay out the `TreeGraph` using them. Further discussion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1827/89).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` and post-process the `EdgeList` of the graph produced by `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph ``

```
edgeList = EdgeList @ # /. PropertyValue[#, VertexLabels]&;
```

Examples:

```
eg1 = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[Sin[Plus[a, b, Times[c,d]]]];

edgeList @ eg1
```

> {Sin -> Plus, Plus -> TagBox["a",HoldForm], Plus -> TagBox["b", HoldForm], Plus-> Times, Times-> TagBox["c", HoldForm], Times-> TagBox["d", HoldForm]}

```
% /. TagBox -> (# &)
```

> {Sin -> Plus, Plus -> "a", Plus -> "b", Plus -> Times, Times -> "c", 
>    Times -> "d"}

Istvan's example:

```
eg2 = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[Hold[Log[Sin[1 + 2], ToExpression["1"<>"0"]]]];

edgeList @ eg2
```

> {Hold->Log, Log -> Sin, Sin -> Plus, Plus -> TagBox[1, HoldForm], Plus -> TagBox[2, HoldForm], Log -> ToExpression, ToExpression -> StringJoin, StringJoin -> TagBox["1", HoldForm], StringJoin -> TagBox["0", HoldForm]}

```
% /. TagBox -> (# &)
```

> {Hold -> Log, Log- > Sin, Sin -> Plus, Plus -> 1, Plus -> 2, Log -> ToExpression, ToExpression -> StringJoin, StringJoin -> "1", StringJoin -> "0"}

With a helper function to put the vertex labels in the centers:

```
reStyle = SetProperty[#, {GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", VertexLabels -> 
 (PropertyValue[# , VertexLabels]/. HoldPattern[a_-> b_]:>Rule[a, Placed[b, Center]])}]&;

reStyle @ eg1
```

[image]

```
reStyle @ eg2
```

[image]