# GridGraph[{6,6,6}] crashes—can you reproduce this?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, crash

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.0**

---

Occasionally, I see a kernel crash with `GridGraph[{6,6,6}]`.  It is not easy to trigger. Sometimes it may require as many as 30 evaluations before it happens, and doing those evaluations in a `Do` loop doesn't trigger it. It is necessary to evaluate separate inputs manually. At other times, I cannot evaluate `GridGraph[{6,6,6}]` even once in a new session as it causes a crash every time.

Here's a screenshot (command line) of how it crashed after 20 evaluations (silent exit):

[image]

So far I could reproduce this with M11.3.0 on macOS 10.13.4. With M11.2.0 I could not.  I would like to know if others can see the crash too, or if it is related to some settings specific to my machine.

---

**Update:** Wolfram Support responded and confirmed the problem within hours after reporting it.

If the problem is significantly inconveniencing you, you can use `IGMakeLattice` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) as a workaround. `IGMakeLattice` was included for other reasons (features not found in `GridGraph`), but it also makes a good workaround for this issue.

Specifically for the 2D and 3D case you may also use

```
gridGraph[dims_List, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := IndexGraph@NearestNeighborGraph[Tuples[Range /@ dims], opt]
```

---

**Update 2:**

It seems that `HypercubeGraph` has a similar crash. My guess is that this is because it might be implemented as `GridGraph[ConstantArray[2,n]]`. Reported as CASE:4064377.

Comment: I have reported (couple days ago) a bug where `ChromaticPolynomial@GridGraph[{2, 2, 2}]` crashed on v11.3, typically couple evaluations after start up of a kernel. It might be related. It never occurred to me that the bug might actually reside in `GridGraph` - could it?

Comment: @kirma It sounds like it might be the same thing. Also, I could only reproduce it with 3D grids, not with 2D ones. Yours is 3D too, also, you are on a Mac too.

Comment: "Wolfram Kernel for Windows has stopped working" too, after around ~20 repetitions. (V11.3, clould not reproduce in V11.2)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this (... a bit) with 2D grids, but didn't succeed. I didn't try too hard, though. My report was accepted as CASE:4054452. Probably you should refer this to them, the root cause might possibly be a similar memory corruption of sorts.

Comment: I've got v11.3 on a new computer (win) and can reproduce the problem.  FWIW v11.2 on RPi doesn't trigger the crash.

Comment: @kirma My report is CASE:4059855. I will tell them that yours may be related.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the confirmation!

Comment: It crashed my 11.3 kernel at the third attempt. This was under Windows 7.

Comment: @Szabolcs same here. crashed every second or third attempt. I am on Windows 10, Mathematica version 11.3

Comment: I can't help but note that indeed the devil is in the details :)