# How to weave Anni Albers Red Meander carpet?

Tags: graphics, generative-art, fractals

Anni Albers (1899 - 1994) was a German artist regarded as one of the most influential textile designers of the 20th century. Since 1931 Albers was head of the Bauhaus weaving workshops in Dessau and Berlin. In 1933 Albers, who was Jewish, fled to North Carolina, where she was invited to teach at the Black Mountain College. Later she became the first textile artist to be honoured with a show at the Museum of Modern Art.

[image]

*Anni Albers in her weaving shop at Black Mountain College, 1937*

One of her carpets reminded me of the famous Hilbert curve:

[image]

*Anni Albers Red Meander, 1954*

My reproduction with Mathematica looks quite nice, but doesn't reflect the randomness and small irregularities of `Red Meander`.

```
Graphics[{Darker @ Red, Thickness[0.025], HilbertCurve[4]},
 Background -> Lighter @ Lighter @ Lighter @ Brown,
 AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

[image]

**Question**

Maybe, a better choice would be a random walk on a square lattice grid using one of the many `Graph` plots. How can we get a better reproduction of  `Red Meander` with `Mathematica`?

Comment: Hm. Looks like a random maze to me. Have look here: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-graphs-and-networks/maze-generator.html

Comment: Btw., I really enjoy your art-related questions and in particular this short vita of Anni Albers. I am from Germany, but have never heard her name before.

Comment: Oh, I also found this https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMaze/

Comment: Thank you, Henrik, probably an Irrgarten (maze) would be the best start

Comment: And here some 3D generalizations: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146156/how-can-mathematica-be-used-to-create-a-3d-maze-with-text-like-this. Googling "random maze mathematica" reveals plenty of different strategies.

Comment: Anni's husband Josef was a mentor to my [childhood neighbor across the street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Anuszkiewicz). I suspect Richard was also influenced by Anni herself.

Comment: Very interesting. The twisted routes of immigration - like the maze of Anni's carpet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An attempt:

**Using `CoordinateBoundsArray` and `FindShortestTour`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cba = Flatten[#, 1] &@CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 20}, {0, 25}}, 1];
st = FindShortestTour[cba, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];
g1 = Graphics[{RGBColor[
   0.6682953195362595, 0.15648222612064008`, 0.2435982997997463, 1.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[8], Line@cba[[Last@st]]}
  , Background -> RGBColor[
   0.8820930848135977, 0.8391520320244056, 0.7687012353458889, 1.]
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03]
  ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

Thanks to @ydd, the addition of the following adds the much needed realism to it.

```
cba += RandomReal[0.05, Dimensions@cba];
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-2**

*The 3D case:*

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cba = Flatten[#, 2] &@
   CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 1];
st = FindShortestTour[cba, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];

g3 = Graphics3D[{
   RGBColor[0.6682953195362595, 0.15648222612064008`, 
    0.2435982997997463, 1.]
   , Tube[cba[[Last@st]], 0.2]
   , {Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[None]
    , Glow@
     RGBColor[0.8820930848135977, 0.8391520320244056, 
      0.7687012353458889, 1.]
    , GeometricTransformation[
     Cuboid @@ Transpose@CoordinateBounds[cba], 
     ScalingTransform[{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}, Mean@cba]]
    }
   }
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03]
  , Boxed -> False
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice. Also fwiw, you can add a small random real to `cba` to get slightly different patterns every time if that is desired:
$$ $$
`cba += RandomReal[0.05, Dimensions@cba];`

$$ $$
And then do `st = ...` This also adds some human-like "imperfections/character" to the the perfectly straight lines :D

Comment: @ydd, Thanks. Your techniques is impressive. I was thinking of ways to add such realism. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Very impressive! (+1) But what about the "T-junction" patterns in original photo?

Comment: Thanks @Silvia, I am still thinking about it. kglr has since added two solutions that address this detail.

Comment: @eldo @Syed also replacing `Line` with `BezierCurve` or `BSplineCurve` looks cool.

Answer (score 11):

We can use [`FindSpanningTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSpanningTree.html) on a `GridGraph` with random edge weights and desired styling to produce a random maze that *looks like* *Red Meander*.

Unlike *Red Meander*, `albersKilim`, being a tree, does not contain cycles; and, being a spanning tree, contains a single connected component. However, like *Red Meander* (and unlike `FindShortestTour`-based approach), it does allow a vertex to be visited multiple times.

```
ClearAll[albersKilim]
albersKilim[dims : {__Integer}, ew_ : Automatic, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{gg = GridGraph[dims, 
     EdgeWeight -> ew /. Automatic -> {e_ :> RandomReal[]}]},
  FindSpanningTree[gg, opts, 
   VertexSize -> 0, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({} &), 
   EdgeStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[8], Darker@Red], 
   Background -> Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Brown, 
   ImagePadding -> 10]]
```

***Examples:***

```
r = 30; c = 20;

SeedRandom[1];

albersKilim[{r, c}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[7];

ew = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[4, 3], r (c - 1) + (r - 1) c];

albersKilim[{r, c}, ew]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];

Multicolumn[
 Table[albersKilim[{20, 20}, Automatic, ImageSize -> 300], 9],
 3]
```

[image]

FWIW, although the output is not anywhere like *Red Meander*, `albersKilim` also  works in 3D:

```
SeedRandom[1]
albersKilim[{10, 10, 10}, 
 RandomReal[1, EdgeCount@GridGraph@{10, 10, 10}], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range@10, 3], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], MaterialShading["Gold"]], 
 Background -> Black, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({CapForm["Square"], Tube[#, .2]} &), 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### Using `GridGraph` with random `EdgeWeight`s and `FindHamiltonianPath`

We modify the `PathGraph` induced by the `HamiltonianPath` by adding/deleting a random number of edges (controlled by options `"NewEdges"` and `"DeletedEdges"`) so that, as in *Red Meander*, the resulting graph may have cycles / multiple connected components / vertices with vertex degree exceeding 2. Using @ydd's suggestion in comments we perturb vertex coordinates by a small random amount (controlled by the option `"Wiggle"`) to get a *more natural look*.

```
ClearAll[albersMeander]

Options[albersMeander] = 
  {"Wiggle" -> .03, 
   "NewEdges" -> 10, 
   "DeletedEdges" -> 5, 
    EdgeWeight -> Automatic, 
    VertexSize -> 0, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> ({} &), 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[8], Darker@Red], 
    Background -> Lighter[Brown, 2/3],
    ImagePadding -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> 300};

albersMeander[dims:{__Integer}, opts:OptionsPattern[{albersMeander, Graph}]] := 
 Module[{pg$, newedges,
    g$ = GridGraph[dims, 
     EdgeWeight -> 
      (OptionValue[EdgeWeight] /. Automatic -> {e_ :> RandomReal[]})]},
  pg$ = PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g$], 
    VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> 
       GraphEmbedding[g$][[v]] + RandomReal[OptionValue["Wiggle"]]}];
  newedges = RandomSample[
    DeleteCases[EdgeList @ g$, 
     Alternatives @@ Join[EdgeList @ pg$, Map[Reverse] @ EdgeList @ pg$]], 
    OptionValue["NewEdges"]];
  Graph[EdgeAdd[EdgeDelete[pg$, 
     RandomSample[EdgeList @ pg$, OptionValue["DeletedEdges"]]], 
    newedges], 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]], 
   FilterRules[Options[albersMeander], Options[Graph]]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

Row[Table[albersMeander[{25, 20}], 3], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Do not add/delete any edges, set `EdgeWeight`s to `1` for all edges and play with the option values for `"Wiggle"`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Row[Map[albersMeander[{25, 20}, 
     EdgeWeight -> {e_ -> 1},
    "Wiggle" -> #, 
    "DeletedEdges" -> 0, "NewEdges" -> 0, 
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], 
      CapForm[# /. {0 -> "Square", _ -> "Round"}], 
      AbsoluteThickness[8], Darker@Red]] &] @ {0, 1/10, 2/10}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Play with different values for `"DeletedEdges"`:

```
SeedRandom[1];

Row[albersMeander[{25, 20}, 
    "DeletedEdges" -> #, 
    "NewEdges" -> 0] & /@ {0, 5, 10, 20},
   Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Play with different values for `"NewEdges"`:

```
SeedRandom[1];

Row[albersMeander[{25, 20}, 
    "DeletedEdges" -> 10, 
    "NewEdges" -> #] & /@ {0, 5, 10, 20},
   Spacer[10]]
```

[image]