# Borromean rings

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions, code-request

how can I plot the Borromean rings in Mathematica?
I am interested in the configuration showcased in figure.
[image: Three rings in linked configuration]

Comment: Three upvotes for displaying an image???

Comment: Look for `BezierFunction`

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BorromeanRingRemoval/ and https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BorromeanMesh/

Comment: 2D is difficult then 3D. A started point maybe https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/293263/72111

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something you can start with:

```
pts = {{-3, 4.5}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4, -4.5}, {3, -4.5}, {4.5, -2}
     , {4.5, 4.5}, {-3, 3}, {5., -4}, {-4.5, -4}, {2, 2}};

Graphics3D[{
  Directive[Black, Glow[RGBColor[.9, .8, .5]]], 
    Rotate[Torus[{0, 2, 1}, {2.5, 3}], 35  Degree, {-1, 0, 0}], 
  Directive[Black, Glow[RGBColor[.9, .8, .5]]], 
    Rotate[Torus[{0, -4, 0}, {1.5, 2}], -135 Degree, {0, 1, 0}], 
  Directive[Black, Glow[RGBColor[.7, .8, .9]]], 
    Tube[BSplineCurve[{Splice@#, 0} & /@ pts, SplineDegree -> 5, SplineClosed -> True], 0.3]
  }, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, 
 ViewVertical -> {1, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]