# Using vtx[] instead of vtx

Tags: functions, function-construction, core-language, functional-style, coding-style

There're two ways to generate a random tree as 1 and 2 below. Both work fine here. So what's the reason to use `vtx[]` instead of `vtx`?

Source: *[How to generate a random tree?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11632/how-to-generate-a-random-tree)*

## 1.

```
vtx[] := Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 50}];
Graph@vtx[]
```

## 2.

```
vtx := Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 50}];
Graph@vtx
```

Comment: The second way is 10 times faster. All rest looks similar.

Comment: It is good to note that the method you linked does not sample trees uniformly. Some trees are generated with higher probability than others. To sample trees uniformly, you can use `IGTreeGame[]` from the IGraph/M package.

Comment: In `2` you could remove the delay from the assignment, since the LHS is not parameterised.

Comment: @Shredderroy `:=` can be removed either in 1 or in 2 (but notice that the right-hand-side generates a random list, so `:=` is important in this application)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason to use 1. is readability. There is no difference in function or performance.

Simply because of established convention, most people when they see `f[vtx]`, they assume that `vtx` is "a variable", i.e. if it is evaluated twice, it will give the same result both times. `vtx[]` looks like "a function call", so people will expect that a second evaluation may give a different result (as it is the case here).

Technically speaking, Mathematica has neither functions nor variables (it is a [term rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting#Term_rewriting_systems)), but it is still useful to think of code in these terms.

Answer (score 12):

Besides the reasons mentioned by @Szabolcs, there's a second advantage of the first method: It is easier to control when evaluation happens.

- With `vtx := …`, evaluation happens as soon as the symbol appears (as long as you're not using stuff with `Hold` attributes/`Unevaluated`)
- With `vtx[] := …`, you can pass around `vtx` without having to worry about evaluation. Only when you add the square brackets is the code actually evaluated.

#### Example

To see why this can be useful, consider the following example: We want to create a function `drawTrees` that creates small plots of 5 randomly sample trees, where we can specify how to sample them.

With `vtx[] := …`, this would look like this:

```
drawTrees[gen_]:= Table[
  Graph[gen[], ImageSize->100],
  5
 ]

vtx[] := Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 20}];
vtx2[] := Flatten@Table[{i <-> i - 1, i <-> f[i]}, {i, 20}];

drawTrees[vtx]
```

[image]

```
drawTrees[vtx2]
```

[image]

With `vtx := …`, we need to use a `HoldFirst` attribute:

```
drawTrees[gen_]:= Table[
  Graph[gen, ImageSize->100],
  5
 ]
Attributes[drawTrees] = {HoldFirst};

vtx := Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 20}];
vtx2 := Flatten@Table[{i <-> i - 1, i <-> f[i]}, {i, 20}];

drawTrees[vtx]
(* same as above *)
drawTrees[vtx2]
(* same as above *)
```

Of course, the fix is simple in this case. But if you need to pass around the generator a lot and store it somewhere, it will become even more messy with the `vtx := …` approach.

Comment: I just wonder if you define `vtx[] := …` then why do you pass `vtx` not `vtx[]`?

Comment: You don't *need* to pass around `vtx` instead of `vtx[]` - the point is that you *can*. I have updated the answer with an example

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the updating.