# FunctionTreeForm

Tags: graphics, functions

I'd like to implement a function *FunctionTreeForm* which takes an arbitrary complex function and renders all the captionable subfunctions in a TreeForm.

- **Explanation**

If we take e.g. a function:

```
TreeForm[Exp[-(x/3)^2]*Cos[2 x + x^2/3]]
```

the corresponding TreeForm is:

[image]

If we tokenize this function into its subfunctions and plot them seperately:

```
{Plot[Exp[-(x/3)^2]*Cos[2 x + x^2/3], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
Plot[E^(-(x^2/9)), {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
Plot[Cos[2 x + x^2/3], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
Plot[2 x + x^2/3, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}
```

we get:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to traverse the corresponding TreeForm and check if a Node is not an Atomic. If it is not I'd suspect it is a function. After collecting all these plots I'd like to display the corresponding TreeForm as a plot of the main function and all its sub-functions in TreeForm.

I played around with Level[] etc. but did not came to a solution that does reliable tokenisation of a function definition into sub-functions and I totally lack any idea how to transfer these into a Tree representation.

- **Why I think this could be a feasible functionality**

I think in education this FunctionTreeFrom could give a good clue how a rather complicated function is actually assembled from its sub-functions.

I hope this is an interesting question and I'm eager to learn how to tackle problems like that.

Comment: Perhaps using [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11470/1517) you can create a `VertexRenderingFunction` that `Inset`s the plot

Comment: Code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846644/utility-to-extract-variables-from-an-expression/5849071#5849071) shows how to extract "variables" inside numeric functions. So you might consider selecting as candidate "functions" those subtrees with a NumericFunction attribute head and containing exactly one variable. Figuring out a sensible plot range is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an approach - I hope this is what you are looking for.
What I did: With cases I just take the nodes that are not Atoms on every level and plot just as you did. Additionally, I included the trees

```
tf = TreeForm[Exp[-(x/3)^2]*Cos[2 x + x^2/3]];

Grid[{Plot[#, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
TreeForm[#, ImageSize -> Small]} & /@ 
Reverse[Cases[tf, x_ /; AtomQ[x] == False, Infinity]]]
```

Alternatively, you could exclude nodes, something like

```
Grid[{Plot[#, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
TreeForm[#, ImageSize -> Small]} & /@ 
Reverse[Cases[tf, x : Except[_Integer | _Symbol | _Rational], Infinity]]]
```

(this could be helpful if you wanted to exclude `Power` or `Times`)

(Edit: I added `Reverse`, to go Top-Down)

**EDIT 2 - Plot in "TreeForm"**
As discussed, I tried to implement the idea that the plots are in actual tree for, i.e. in the respective vertices. Here's how I tried to do it - I am sure there are better ways...
Please note that I didn't thoroughly test the function, so any feedback is welcome.

TODO: One problem I couldn't solve is the `ImageSize`. I did link it to `LeafCount`, but sometimes you want to add some pixels or make it smaller. For now, you can use the 4th argument of the function to adjust. Any ideas welcome!

So the function:

```
ClearAll[functionTree];
functionTree[function_, plotMin_, plotMax_, imSizeCorrection_, 
correction_: 0.3] := Module[{tree, nodes, pos, rules},
   tree = TreeForm[function];
   nodes = Union[Cases[tree, x_ :> {x, Position[tree, x]}, Infinity]];
   pos = Flatten[nodes[[All, 2]], 1];
   rules = 
     Flatten[Position[pos, #][[1, 1]] -> 
     Position[pos, Most[#]][[1, 1]] & /@ Cases[pos, Except[{1}]]];
   TreePlot[rules, Automatic, Position[pos, {1}][[1, 1]], 
     ImageSize -> LeafCount[function]*100 + imSizeCorrection, 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], 
     Rectangle[#1 - correction, #1 + correction], Black, 
     Text[Plot[
     nodes[[Position[nodes, pos[[#2]], Infinity][[1, 1]], 1]], {x,
       plotMin, plotMax}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      nodes[[Position[nodes, pos[[#2]], Infinity][[1, 1]], 
        1]]], #1]} &)]
]
```

e.g. function call:

```
functionTree[Exp[-(x/3)^2]*Cos[2 x + x^2/3], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 0, 0.3]
```

What it does: first we collect all `nodes`, killing duplicates. In `pos` we keep all positions, i.e. all nodes in the tree. Next, `rules` generates the edges of the tree (i.e. it finds the respective roots, except for the top node). Next we can plot it all - with above discussed problem (`ImageSize` that is). We use `VertexRenderingFunction` to get it done.

Note that `nodes` and `pos` in this construction do not necessarily have the same `Length`, for there can be several nodes with the same content (such as `x`).

Also note: I figured I might just as well plot all nodes - why exculde the non-atomic ones after all? - else see the first answer.

I hope this helps - feedback very welcome, especially on the ImageSize thingie.

(first img removed)

[image]

Comment: Hello :) The tokenization looks perfect! +1 What would be perfect now is to replace the nodes in TreeForm with the plots. In that case using FunctionTreeForm is a TreeForm with the subplots of the function.

Comment: @Stefan - glad it helps! So you want the plots in the respective nodes of the tree? Sorry I misunderstood - will think about that

Comment: @Stefan: I posted and edit, I hope this helps. Please note the problem with the ImageSize...

Comment: Hello. That looks quite good and the code is pretty readable. Wow! How about the idea, to deal with the ImageSize, only plot the non-trivial functions ergo leaving out straight line functions only curves. That would reduce the plots and increase the plot range/size. What do you think?

Comment: The problem I had was more about the "scalabiltity" of the image - ie. the proportions of the rectangles we're off if you use a shorter expression, such as `Sin[x]`, hence the correction term there. I am afraid I have to run now, I hope my answer is self-expl. enough!

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you for your effort in this.

Comment: Forgot to accept. Apologise.

Comment: No worries - as long as it does its job