# Visualizing nested lists for easier human understanding

Tags: list-manipulation, visualization, curated-data

When interacting with *Mathematica*, I often find myself staring blankly at waves of curly braces, trying to understand how data is organized hierarchically. For example, the beginning of the result to

```
WolframAlpha["temperature in Toronto yesterday", "DataRules"]
```

looks like this:

[image: Waves of curly braces]

To visualize the hierarchy, I typically turn to [TreeForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeForm.html), but that's often unwieldy. There's no way to collapse parts of the tree you don't care about (as there would be in, say, a file system browser), so the visualization frequently spreads well off screen or is illegibly small. For example,

```
TreeForm[WolframAlpha["temperature in Toronto yesterday", "DataRules"]]
```

produces:

[image: TreeForm of a WolframAlpha query]

Is there a better way?

Comment: "staring blankly at waves of curly braces" is a song by Pink Floyd

Comment: `TableForm` works pretty well for that particular example.

Comment: Is something like this what you are looking for? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29341#29341

Comment: Or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/transform-an-expression-into-a-graph-that-can-be-plotted-with-treegraph-not-tre)?

Comment: Thanks for the lead, @Mike. [`TraceView`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29341#29341) led me to the [`OpenerTree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Views.html#483391171) example in Virtual Book, which is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = WolframAlpha["temperature in Toronto yesterday", "DataRules"];
```

Is this enough?

```
Column[OpenerView[{#, Switch[Head[#2], 
   List, Pane[Column@#2, {Full, 200}, Scrollbars -> True], 
   _, #2]}
] & @@@ data]
```

> [image]

Comment: Certainly works well for Wolfram Alpha output, which has a consistent nesting structure. For arbitrarily nested lists, I'm still using [`OpenerTree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Views.html#483391171) from Virtual Book.