# Graph that shows how symbols are used in an expression

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement, expression-construction

I would like to make a graph to show how symbols build up an expression. For example, the matrix multiplication

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 d & e & f \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 g & h \\
 i & j \\
 k & l \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

looks like:

[image]

The code is:

```
A={{a,b,c},{d,e,f}};
B={{g,h},{i,j},{k,l}};
expr=A.B//Flatten;
expr2edges[ee_]:=Table[arg->ee,{arg,List@@ee}]
edges={};
For[ii=2,ii<Depth[expr],ii++,
    newEdges=(expr2edges/@Level[expr,{-ii}]);
    AppendTo[edges,newEdges]
]
Graph[Flatten[edges],VertexLabels->Automatic]
```

My intent is so close to an inverted `TreeForm` that I feel there must be a better way to write this. Possibly with a clever use of patterns & replacement.

**How can I improve my code?** Is [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/transform-an-expression-into-a-graph-that-can-be-plotted-with-treegraph-not-tre) the right way to go about it -- with Sow / Reap?

Thanks folks.

Comment: Cheating: `Graph[Flatten[Inner[{##} -> Times[##] &, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{g, h}, {i, j}, {k, l}}, Thread /@ {##, Map[Last, {##}] -> Total[Map[Last, {##}]]} &]], GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

Answer (score 9):

Let us use `IGExpressionTree` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). This function returns a `Graph` of the expression tree where the vertex names are the positions of subexpressions.

[image]

```
expr = Flatten[( {
     {a, b, c},
     {d, e, f}
    } ).( {
     {g, h},
     {i, j},
     {k, l}
    } )]
```

```
Graph[
 Join @@ Function[expr,
    Map[
     First@Extract[expr, {#}] &,
     EdgeList@ReverseGraph@IGExpressionTree[expr],
     {2}
     ]
    ] /@ expr,
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
]
```

[image]

Or a bit simpler:

```
Graph[
 EdgeList@ReverseGraph@VertexDelete[IGExpressionTree[expr], {}] /. 
    pos : {___Integer} :> First@Extract[expr, {pos}],
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
]
```

---

**Update:** Here's a very compact way that does not use IGraph/M:

```
Graph[
 Reap[expr /. t : _[___, s_, ___] /; (Sow[s -> t]; False) -> Null][[-1, 1]],
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
]
```

[image]

I used `ReplaceAll` to traverse the expression tree, recording the edges as we go. We put a [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) on the pattern that always returns `False`, forcing the traversal to go through the entire expression. As part of evaluating the condition, the relevant information is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[e_] := TransitiveReductionGraph[RelationGraph[And[UnsameQ[##], Not[FreeQ[#2, #]]] &, 
   DeleteDuplicates@Level[e, All]], VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]

f @ expr
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another post-processing answer to get a `Graph` directly from the `TreeForm`. It won't perform as well as Szabolcs' answer but it certainly works fine:

```
ClearAll[treeGraph]
treeGraph[exp_] :=
 Module[{gc, coordinates, nodes, labels, edges, g1},
  gc = ToExpression[ToBoxes@TreeForm[exp]][[1, 1]];
  labels = 
   Association@
    Cases[gc, Inset[expr_, pos_, ___] :> pos -> expr, \[Infinity]];
  edges = 
   DirectedEdge @@@ 
    Flatten@Cases[gc, Line[pairs : {__}, ___] :> Rule @@@ pairs, 
      Infinity];
  coordinates = gc[[1]];
  g1 =
   Graph[
    edges,
    VertexLabels -> Normal@Map[Placed[#, Center] &, labels],
    VertexSize -> Tiny
    ];
  Graph[g1, VertexCoordinates -> coordinates[[VertexList[g1]]]]
  ]
```

We can do all the basic `Graph` stuff with this too:

```
gg = expr // treeGraph
```

[image]

```
gg // AdjacencyMatrix // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Comment: But this (and kglr's) duplicates nodes. I think the OP wanted only one `a` node with two out-edges, instead of two nodes each with one out-edge.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't read carefully enough. I just thought the OP wanted a `Graph` from `TreeForm`. I'll leave this thing up since it's a convenient function that I might want in the future, but clearly it doesn't answer the question.