# Permutations of 0's and 1's in a lower-triangular matrix

Tags: matrix, permutation

For a given $n \ge 5$ create every $n$-by-$n$ matrix containing exactly four $1$'s strictly below the diagonal and $0$'s elsewhere.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-to-generate-random-directed-acyclic-graphs

Comment: I don't see why you wrote "randomly" if then you want "all permutations"

Comment: @belisarius Ah, that explains my original misunderstanding (I voted to close as duplicate of the above then retracted the vote ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
indices = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, 5}, {j, 1, i - 1}], 1];
allarrays = SparseArray[# -> 1, 5] & /@ Subsets[indices, {4}];
```

The code generates 210 such matrices (see `Length@allarrays`). Here is a sample of one of them:

```
allarrays[[3]] // Normal

(* Out:
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here is a **general function** to accomplish the task:

```
generator[n_Integer] := Module[
   {indices, allarrays},
   indices = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, n}, {j, 1, i - 1}], 1];
   allarrays = SparseArray[# -> 1, n] & /@ Subsets[indices, {n - 1}]
 ]
```

You can check the output against the $n=5$ case shown above:

```
generator[5] == allarrays

(* Out: True *)
```

Keep in mind that the number of matrices to be generated blows up really quickly and the results take quite a bit of space in memory as well. For instance:

```
results = generator[8]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length[results]
ByteCount[results]/1024.^3 (* to convert to GB *)

(* Out:
{11.9763, Null}
1 184 040
0.996862
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Eh, what the heck... With `RandomSample` and `ReplacePart`:

```
With[{ss = Subsets[Flatten@
 MapIndexed[Range[#1, #2 + #1 - 1] &, Range[6, 21, 5]], {4}]},
 Partition[ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 25], Thread[# -> 1]], 5] & /@ ss]
```

And...

```
MatrixForm/@%
```

[image]

Comment: You are generating only one instance, not ALL of them as requested.

Comment: @MarcoB... oops, Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A variant:

```
f[i_, j_, n_] := n (i - 1)  + j
fun[n_] := f[##, n] & @@@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}]
sa[n_] := Module[{r = Subsets[fun[n], {4}]},
  Transpose@Partition[SparseArray[Thread[# -> 1], n^2], n] & /@ r]
```

`sa`produces the desired matrices (in this case with 4 "ones" in elements below diagonal.

```
Length[sa@#] & /@ Range[5, 10]
```

shows the growth with argument: {210, 1365, 5985, 20475, 58905, 148995}

Visualizing first 9 elements for n=5,...,10.

```
vis[n_] := 
 Grid[Partition[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> Automatic] & /@ sa[n][[1 ;; 9]], 
   3]]
ListAnimate[vis /@ Range[5, 10]]
```

[image]