# How to generate a DAG with given number of node and edge?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The node of the graph is n,edge of the graph is m:
How can I generate a DAG randomly with node n and edge m?

Comment: I recommend not the accepted answer, but this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2266/12